# Se pierde la conexión al servidor remoto mysql java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Uso esta cadena de conexión para conectarme a una base de datos:
[image: codigo de conexion]

Cuando lo ejecuto en red local todo va bien pero al direccionar a un servidor remoto (internet) me sale el error de la imagen siguiente cuando tardo en rellenar unos datos parece que se desconecta, me pueden dar una mano por favor?? gracias

[image: error al conectarse a servidor remoto]

Comment: es porque el método Conexión no retorna nada, prueba transformándolo a public Connection Conexion() y que este retorne la variable conexion

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta, pero no entiendo bien, me puedes dar mas alcances por favor

Comment: Corrigiendo las etiquetas ya que no es un problema específico de netbeans, ni se produce al interactuar con netbeans sin tu proyecto abierto

Comment: En el stacktrace no veo la llamada a conexion. Deberia estar por algún lado. Por otro lado, en el metodo getConnection() asumes que la conexión ya se realizó y puede que no sea cierto. En este método asegúrate que connection sea diferente a NULL, de lo contrario llama a Conexion.